# Jenkins : copy artifacts(jar file) to a remote linux server , Publish Over SSH plugin

Tags: jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to transfer build jar file from jenkins(currently installed on my local Mac machine) to a linux server.

I have setup `publishOverSSH plugin` in Jenkins and have done neccessary setup, but when I do a test configuration I get this error:

> Failed to connect or change directory
>   jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to connect and initialize SSH connection. Message: [Failed to connect session for config [rn-boltd-lappxx.rno.XYZ.com]. Message [Auth fail]]

Log file says:

```
WARNING [Handling POST /jenkins/descriptorByName. /jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration/testConnection from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 : http-nio-8080-exec-5] 
jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration.connect Failed to connect session for config [rn-boltd-lapp24.rno.apple.com]. Message [Auth fail]
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration.connect(BapSshHostConfiguration.java:380)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration.createClient(BapSshHostConfiguration.java:245)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshHostConfiguration.createClient(BapSshHostConfiguration.java:234)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.descriptor.BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.validateConnection(BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.java:180)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.descriptor.BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.doTestConnection(BapSshPublisherPluginDescriptor.java:175)
at jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.descriptor.BapSshHostConfigurationDescriptor.doTestConnection(BapSshHostConfi
```

I am running jenkins on MAc 10.13.6.
Jenkins in running on apache tomcat 9.0.1

I am able to schedule basic build jobs, connectivity from git is working fine.

I have generated id_rsa and id_rsa.pub keys on my local MAC using ssh-keygen tool.

I am able to do ssh to my linux server using simple shell script in jenkins.

When I go to `Manage Jenkins>Configure System> Publish Over SSH section` :
Passphrase : I entered the LDAP password i use to login to my linux server.

Path to key :

- Path to my RSA key : `/Users/neha922102/.ssh/id_rsa`
- Key : Pasted the above key

SSH Server section:

- Name: name of server
- Hostname : `rn-boltd-lappxx.rno.XYZ.com`
- username : `c4986148`
- Remote Directory : `/tmp`

I have also copied the `is_rsa.pub` key to the remote linux server under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
c4986148@rn-boltd-lappXX(Linux-RENO::DEV):~/.ssh]$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 c4986148 aplstaff 745 May  7 05:37 authorized_keys
```

I am not root user here, so I cannot restart the ssh service.

Configuration seems fine, then why am I getting this error.

I should be able to connect with SSH and then copy artifacts via SSH when build succeeds.

Comment: VERSION: Jenkins ver. 2.170

Comment: check on which user jenkins executor runs (just echo username in jenkins pipeline) then check if this user has the proper configuration.

Comment: u mean to say, I should create a new pipeline job . and in script section`, I should write "echo username" and then save and click "Build Now" to see the output.?

Comment: Yes or whatever that will display the current username.

Comment: Started by user Neha
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/neha922102/.jenkins/workspace/pipelineTest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build user)
[Pipeline] wrap
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Neha
Neha
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // wrap
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: it displays "Neha" user, which I created in Jenkins.

Comment: what configuration should I check in this user. When go to confiure> Neha User in Jenkins, I added the SSH public key in the key section.

Comment: Now I get this exception:   Failed to connect or change directory

jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to add SSH key. Message [invalid privatekey: [B@e33f51e]